# Goto definition option no longer in right click menu

Tags: sublimetext3

When i started working on my angularjs project in Sublime Text 3, I used to get a "Goto definition" option in the right click menu, But it has disappeared since the last few weeks and I am unable to understand why.

Also the Goto Definition in general(F12) does't seem to work anymore. It gives and error

> Unable to find myFunction

But the "Goto symbol in Project" does seem to work.

Can someone help with what exactly must have gone wrong? and how do get it back?

Comment: have you installed any new packages or have any installed packages been updated recently?

Comment: Yes, I keep adding and removing packages from time to time. How do I know which one is the cause?

Comment: Not sure there is a quick/easy way... You could disable each package one by one (`Command Palette -> Package Control: Disable Package`) and check when it starts working again, then re-enable all but the last package you disabled.

Comment: @KeithHall thanks for that tip it helped. The problem was with a Javscript Syntax package that I had added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a javascript syntax highlighting package that I had installed which turned out to be the cause. 
As mentioned be user KeithHall in the question comments, I tried disabling my installed packages one by one to find the package that was causing the issue.

The goto definition option is now back in the Right Click menu, also the F12 feature works correctly.

Thanks again to the commentor